# Hide Save for the later use magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2.7

Hello i have one custom payment method, in that you can done payment through the credit card and debit card, i have one problem there is one checkbox "Save for the later use" , i want to hide that checkbox if customer is not login

```
                <!-- ko if: (hasVerification())-->
                <div class="half-width">
                    <div class="field cvv required" data-bind="attr: {id: getCode() + '_cc_type_cvv_div'}, visible: isCcFormShown">
                        <div class="control _with-tooltip">
                            <input type="password"
                                class="input-text cvv"
                                name="payment[cc_cid]"
                                value=""
                                maxlength="4"
                                data-bind="attr: {id: getCode() + '_cc_cid',
                                title: $t('Card Verification Number'),
                                placeholder:$t('Card Verification Number'),
                                'data-container': getCode() + '-cc-cvv',
                                'data-validate': JSON.stringify({'required-number':true, 'validate-cc-cvn':'#' + getCode() + '_cc_type'})},
                                enable: true,
                                value: creditCardVerificationNumber" />
                            <div class="field-tooltip toggle">
                                <span class="field-tooltip-action action-cvv"
                                    tabindex="0"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                                    data-bind="attr: {title: $t('What is this?')}, mageInit: {'dropdown':{'activeClass': '_active'}}">
                                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'What is this?'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                                </span>
                                <div class="field-tooltip-content"
                                    data-target="dropdown"
                                    data-bind="html: getCvvImageHtml()"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-grp">
                <div class="field number" data-bind="">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" class="input-text" value="" maxlength="50"
                            data-bind="attr: {
                                    autocomplete: off,
                                    id: getCode() + '_cc_holder_name',
                                    title: $t('Card Holder Name'),
                                    placeholder:$t('Card Holder Name'),
                                    'data-container': getCode() + '-cc-holder-name',
                                },
                            enable: isActive($parents)"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-grp choice-wrap" >

                <div class="half-width">
                    <div class="field choice" >
                        <input type="checkbox"
                            name="vault[is_enabled]"
                            class="checkbox"
                            data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '_enable_vault'}" />
                        <label class="step-title label" data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode() + '_enable_vault'}" >
                            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Save for later use.'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="half-width">
                    <div class="payment-method-content">
                        <div class="actions-toolbar">
                            <div class="primary">
                                <button class="action primary checkout"
                                        type="submit"
                                        data-bind="
                                        click: preparePayment,
                                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                                        css: {disabled: false}
                                        "
                                        disabled>
                                    <span data-bind="text: $t('Place Order')"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </div>                   
        </fieldset>
    </form>


</div>
```

Comment: Which custom payment method you are using? Is any reference on GIT for that method, So we can see and update you accordingly.

Comment: If you have to custom module, Then you might get that code in HTML template. you can make it display done.

Comment: Please check my updated question @RaviSoni

Comment: Can you check my code? @RaviSoni

Comment: Here, Actually, you have to debug step by step. To identify which checkbox is there.
By removing each one by one you can identify.

Comment: <input type="checkbox"
                            name="vault[is_enabled]"
                            class="checkbox"
                            data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '_enable_vault'}" />
                        <label class="step-title label" data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode() + '_enable_vault'}" >
                            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Save for later use.'--><!-- /ko --></span> , here is the checkbox code which i want to hide if customer is not login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95573/discussion-between-magento-and-ravi-soni).

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

In your html file add below condition.

```
<span data-bind="if: isLogedIn">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vault[is_enabled]" class="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '_enable_vault'}" /> <label class="step-title label" data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode() + '_enable_vault'}" > <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Save for later use.'--><!-- /ko --></span> 
</span>
```

Next, in your KO js file add below code.

declare object of 'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer' in your define function. like this

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',        
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,        
        customer
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
        });
        ......

});
```